# Is it possible to send response from php server to iphone?

Tags: php, iphone

i am posting form from iphone to php, where data is collected and inserted to database.how should i get response from server that data is success fully inserted in tables?

Comment: i need confirmation from server that query executed successfully & data is inserted in tables. if not i request user to resubmit form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until you tell us more about what you are doing I would say:

```
echo "ok";
```

Comment: i need confirmation from server that query executed successfully & data is inserted in tables. if not i request user to resubmit form.

Comment: i have a noob question. Once I echo this in my PHP, how can I get this response from my iPhone? Is the only way possible using StringWithContentsofURL? Because if I use that, it runs the code on the website again, something I do not want. Thanks!

Comment: Please use [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) If you want to create a new question.